# How to put 2 elements inline in ReactJs Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to put 1 form group and 1 button in 1 line. I read, that it was possible to do with css.But I don't want to add additional css to my project. Are there any instruments in React bootstrap to control elements location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `<Form inline>`:

```
<Form inline>
  <FormGroup>
  </FormGroup>
  <Button type="submit">
    Submit
  </Button>
</Form>
```

See [this](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#forms-inline) for details.